# KEEP_AWAKE, but turn off screen to save battery?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, air-android

I have built a fun little MP3 player using FlashDevelop and Flash CS5.5 IDE (no Flex).

The app 'emulates' old school style radio by fading tracks from any chosen m3u playlist while interspersing random radio stabs, silly fake ads and dj chatter (much like Flash FM from GTA Vice City).

The app itself works very well, however, if I set `SystemIdleMode.NORMAL` the app stops when the screen saver kicks in, and when I set to `SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE`, the screen never kicks in and the app runs until the battery dies ... which unfortunately doesn't take too long ;)

Is it possible to 'disable' the screen while leaving the app running to help save battery?

If no, can I at least control brightness, and perhaps display a black overlay? Would this have much effect on battery life?

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Cheers.